# In Java, is it required a Collator for exact utf-8 string matching?

Tags: java, utf-8, internationalization

When comparing two utf-8 strings (one being the text and the other being the pattern to find) in java for an exact match, is it required to use a Collator or is it enough to normalize both strings and use a simple charAt comparison?

For more information about internationalized text search and the use of Collators, please look at http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/java/text-searching-java-050524-1453/

**Example**: In Spanish "ch" may be a single letter, while in English is 2 letters. So the word "Chiapas" may look the same, but if that is not taken into consideration, the match will fail.

Comment: What do you mean by "UTF-8 strings"? By the time it's a *String* in Java, the original binary encoding is irrelevant.

Comment: Can you give us an example of two Strings that are "exact matches" as an edge case, so we know what you mean?

Comment: Example: In Spanish "ch" may be a single letter, while in English is 2 letters. So the word "Chiapas" may look the same, but if that is not taken into consideration, the match will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search exact matches I think normalization is enough. You will need `Collator` if for instance only `Collator.PRIMARY` differences make sense.

Answer (score 1):

`String.equals` already does a comparison char-by-char, so for an exact match (i.e.,  not considering [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization), etc.), you can use it.

Comment: I need to consider normalization because I am going to be handling text in different languages.

Comment: @rreyes So what is an "exact match" for you?

Comment: RReyes, it will do a char by char match.  What Artefacto is hinting at is if you are using string replacement through the internationalization libraries, it will not match the Italian version of the String to the German one.  Same language matches are not an issue.

Comment: @rreyes By the way, "I need to consider normalization because I am going to be handling text in different languages" doesn't really make sense to me; I don't see the causality.

Comment: @Artefacto Find all the places where a pattern appears in a text.

Comment: @Edwin What I was hinting at was this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization

Comment: @rreys, ah, yes forgot about unicode normalization, even though it recently crossed my radar in a PDF searching routine.

Comment: @Artefacto Look at the example I just included. I hope that makes the question more clear.

Comment: @rreyes So what you mean by "exact match" is actually a more loose (in the sense that more pairs will match) comparison that takes into account language idiosyncrasies? In that case, yes, you'll have to use collators.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [String.equals()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

FYI `String.getBytes()` method [returns an array of bytes in UTF-8 format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html), but that shouldn't be relevant to comparing for "exact match" - that's what String.equals(String) does.

Comment: Strings are Unicode in Java. I dont think they are UTF-8 ... but I might be wrong on that one.

Comment: String are unicode yes, but getbytes returns UTF-8 bytes - see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html

Answer (score 0):

Collators are for sorting. String.equals() is for equality comparisons.